# If I don't receive the item, Do you guarantee the refund?

Tags: tense

I'm planning to buy some items from online shop on the internet, but I couldn't find their refund policy on their web-site. So I want to send them an email to check if they guarantee the refund in-case that I don't receive the item.

what tense should I use, all tenses sound well. So I'm not sure.

> If I **don't receive** the item,  Do you guarantee the refund?
>   If I **haven’t received** the item,  Do you guarantee the refund?
>   If I **won't receive** the item,  Do you guarantee the refund?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If I **don't receive the item**, do you guarantee a refund?

This is the best as is, since there is no time issue. You just don't have it at the time you might request a refund.

> If I **haven’t received the item by May 15**, do you guarantee a refund?

Use this if there is some promise of delivery by some date.

But don't use

> If I **won't receive the item**, do you guarantee a refund?

unless you can predict the future, or know you will never receive it.

Answer (score 4):

The first option is best:

> If I **don't receive** the item, Do you guarantee the refund?

But it's better to change "the" to "a" as follows:

> If I **don't receive** the item, Do you guarantee **a** refund?

Comment: And you should probably change the `D` for a `d`.